# GROUP BY in combination with XML

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to this (of course, this is just example content):

```
ID           xml          some_other_value      even_more_values           ....
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GUID1        <A />                      1   
GUID1        <A />                                            2
GUID1        <A />                      1                   
GUID2        <B />                      3                     4
```

Is it possible to group by ID, when one of the fields that should be grouped contains xml content? It is possible that duplicates exist in these rows, or column values can be null, but of course they never contain different values for the same ID.

I want the table to look like this:

```
ID           xml          some_other_value      even_more_values            ....
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GUID1        <A />                      1                     2
GUID2        <B />                      3                     4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number() over()`.

```
select *
from (
       select *,
              row_number() over(partition by ID order by (select 0)) as rn
       from YourTable 

     ) T
where T.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the xml to varchar and group by that

```
 group by convert(varchar(max),xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.
Convert xml to varchar

```
select distinct t.id,t.xml,t1.first t1,t2.second t2
from test t
inner join test t1 on t1.id=t.id and t1.first is not null
inner join test t2 on t2.id=t.id and t2.second is not null;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69377/4)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like:

```
select * 
from
    (select 
      id
      ,max(isnull(someothervalue,0)) as someothervalue
      ....
    from table
    group by id) si
cross apply (select top 1 xml from table where id = si.id) xmli(xml)
```